# send checkbox value through formgroup in angular

Tags: angular

i am new in angular, i want to send checkbox value in the formgroup. i have 2 checkbox in the field can some one help me.

```
masterList: {
        type: String,
        read: true,
        write: true
    },
    eventlist:{
        type: String,
        read: true,
    },
    feedBackSubmission: {
        type: String,
        read: true,
        write: true
}
```

this is my json i want to send their name and read an write value from my page

this is my html code

```
 <tr>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Feedback Submission</th>
       <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        </tr>
```

this is my ts

```
  roleForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [null, [Validators.required]],
    description: [null, [Validators.required]],
    feedBackSubmission:[null,[Validators.required]],
    // eventStatusList:[null,[Validators.required]],
    // exercisestatus:[null,[Validators.required]],
    // uservariableList:[null,[Validators.required]],

  });
```

i want to send the value of these checkbox(true/false) in the form

Answer (score 0):

This is for a table? if it's, you will need a different approach.

i make based on whitout table.

HTML

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="roleForm">
    <tr>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Feedback Submission</th>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <input formControlName="feedBackSubmission" type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

TS

```
this.roleForm = this.fb.group({
  name: [null, [Validators.required]],
  description: [null, [Validators.required]],
  feedBackSubmission: [null, [Validators.required]]
});
```

Form value

```
{
    "name": null,
    "description": null,
    "feedBackSubmission": true
}
```

[Stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-viu5kn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: sir yes sir this is for table in table ,i have 2 option i.e read and write and i want to pass both the value in your example you pass only one value

Comment: In this case you will need to use FormArray. [this is a sample with material table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/table-form-array)